# Problems with WCF deserialising SOAP array containing polymorphic objects

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl

I have a problem with a WCF web services that is deserialising an array of polymorphic objects. The server side is not WCF, but I created the stubs from WSDL. The important parts in WSDL are

```
<complexType name="NodeList">
    <sequence>
        <element name="data" type="cmtypes:Node" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

and

```
<complexType name="Device">
    <sequence>
        <element name="uniqueKey" type="xsd:unsignedLong" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <element name="revision" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        [...}
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="Node">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="cmtypes:Device">
            <sequence>
                <element name="cmdaemonUrl" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <element name="networks" type="cmtypes:NetworkInterfaceList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
                [...]
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

<complexType name="MasterNode">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="cmtypes:Node">
            <sequence>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

VS created the following type for the list:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIncludeAttribute(typeof(MasterNode))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIncludeAttribute(typeof(SlaveNode))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIncludeAttribute(typeof(VirtualSMPNode))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIncludeAttribute(typeof(VirtualNode))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIncludeAttribute(typeof(PhysicalNode))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.brightcomputing.com/cmtypes.xsd")]
public partial class Node : Device {

    private string cmdaemonUrlField;

    [...]
}
```

However, if I receive a message containing a master node like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cmtypes="http://www.brightcomputing.com/cmtypes.xsd" xmlns:cmdevice="http://www.brightcomputing.com/cmdevice.wsdl">
    <s:Header xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"></s:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <cmdevice:getNodesResponse SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
            <nodes xsi:type="cmtypes:NodeList" xmlns="">
                <data xsi:type="cmtypes:MasterNode">
                    <uniqueKey xsi:type="xsd:unsignedLong">38654705666</uniqueKey>
                    <revision xsi:type="xsd:string"></revision>
                    <modified xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</modified>
                    <toBeRemoved xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</toBeRemoved>
[...]
```

the whole stuff explodes with a `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException` saying "Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'getNodes'." and "Object cannot be stored in an array of this type." in the inner exception. Why? What can I do to fix this (the stub generation)?

I have absolutely no clue due to very limited WCF/SOAP knowledge, so any help is appreciated.

Best regards,
Christoph

*Edit:* It might be relevant that the response actually contains "data" elements of different, polymorphic types, i.e. `cmtypes:MasterNode` and `cmtypes:PhysicalNode`.

*Edit:* Could it be that the Stub and the Message do not go together? As I understand, the stub expects a `data` property, which is an array:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.brightcomputing.com/cmtypes.xsd")]
public partial class NodeList : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private Node[] dataField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public Node[] data {
        get {
            return this.dataField;
        }
        set {
            this.dataField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("data");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

However, in my answer I get a `NodeList` directly containing a sequence of `data` elements, which are actually nodes or derived from nodes:

```
<cmdevice:getNodesResponse SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <nodes xsi:type="cmtypes:NodeList" xmlns="">
        <data xsi:type="cmtypes:MasterNode">
            <uniqueKey xsi:type="xsd:unsignedLong">38654705666</uniqueKey>

            [...]
        </data>
        <data xsi:type="cmtypes:PhysicalNode">
            <uniqueKey xsi:type="xsd:unsignedLong">38654705669</uniqueKey>
            [...]
        </data>
    [...]
```

Do you think I can fix that somehow by injecting a behavior in WCF? My big problem is that I have absolutely no possibility of chaning the server side...

Comment: Where is a definition for cmtypes:NetworkInterfaceList?

Comment: It is in the WSDL. I omitted it (and a lot of other stuff) for brevity, but if it matters, I can post it.

Comment: please publish the whole wsdl (including referenced schema) and the whole return soap. you can also mail me if it is confidential.

Comment: The problem is that the complete WSDL simply exceeds the allowed message size on Stackoverflow. However, I have uploaded it to SkyDrive: https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=ef9379e2210fc4ba&resid=EF9379E2210FC4BA!416&parid=EF9379E2210FC4BA!122

Comment: Could you upload the .wsdl AND the referenced .xsd files? The .wsdl is just not enough. The referenced http://www.brightcomputing.com/cmtypes.xsd is just a URI, but no URL.

Comment: That is part of the problem - basically nothing is working out-of-the-box and I must fix the stubs generated from the WSDL manually before I can do anything. I believe I know you phone (...483) - perhaps it would be best if I give you a call provided I am right.

Comment: Btw, I believe they are just using "brightcomputing.com/cmtypes.xsd" as namespace; could this by the case? The complexTypes etc. are included in the WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting this is going to be hard. One thing I would try is using [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5wt2he6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to see if it can deserialize then start reducing the message until you get the offending type.